# Where do I put a .desktop file so the launcher can always show it?

Tags: unity, launcher

I recently installed e-Sword on my 12.04 Unity laptop. The installation creates a desktop icon of the application. I dragged the icon to the launcher and the icon was created in the launcher. But, when I move the desktop icon to trash, the launcher icon also disappears. What I need to do to delete the desktop icon without the launcher icon disappearing?

Answer (score 22):

You can copy the .desktop into `~/.local/share/applications`

Basically you're doing the end steps of this:

- [How can I edit/create new launcher items in Unity by hand?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand)

After this the application will show up in the Dash, then you can either drag it to the launcher or run it and right click "Lock to Launcher".

Comment: Adding it to /usr/share/applications also works, but you will need privileges.

Comment: For those wondering: The difference is that shortcuts in `/usr/share/applications` are available for every user, while those in `~/.local/share/applications` are user-specific.

Answer (score 1):

Right click the icon on the Launcher, and choose Keep in Launcher

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Work around. Moved the desktop icon to the e-Sword folder created on my home folder by the installation, and from there, I dragged and drop to the Launcher.

Answer (score 0):

desktop files are stored: globally in /usr/share/applications, locally in ~/.local/share/applications. You can use the below format to create a .desktop file for your app using a text-editor:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=PyCharm 3.0
Comment=Jetbrains Python IDE
Exec=/home/sysadmin/programs/pycharm-community-3.0/bin
Icon=/home/sysadmin/programs/pycharm-community-3.0/bin/pycharm.png
Categories=Application;Development;Python;IDE
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=0
```

Alternatively, you may do a "unix sacrilege", and use one of those GUI tools out there! Once you've created the .desktop file in the corresponding path, you may find it though the dash. To make it stick permanently to the launcher, just right-click and say "Lock to Launcher" as LnxSlck has mentioned

Answer (score 0):

arronax is a great gui tool for creating application launchers and it allows you add the icon, description, etc then pressing the menu down arrow button it create the .desktop file for you.    All you have to do is move it to its permanent location.

http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/arronax/

There's 3 .deb files on the arronax site which you have to download and install w/ sw center, gdebi or synaptic.   And I forget the order but you do it in a certain sequence.

It works really well though.